# how do you change back the style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change back the style of a html element to its style="" parameter. I know that you change back an element style to its class, but is there any way to change back to its style="" in javascript? In another way, I've changed the style of it in javascript using element.style, and I basically want to be able to undo it and return it to be what it was after the style="", not the class, is this even possible and if it is, how do i do it?

I tried element.style.color = ""; and element.style.color = null; but they both just reset it to the text color in its class, where in its style="" the element color was changed to a different color, and i wanted it to change back to the color in its style.

Comment: In a general sense, setting any value anywhere to its previous state would involve storing that previous state somewhere and then updating to that value.  Is that what you're doing?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: why not just save the old style in a variable `const oldStyle = element.style` and when you need to restore it you just set it back `element.style = oldStyle`?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  If you remove the style attribute or remove the styles defined in it, the element will be styled based on styles for its class or id.  What styles do you want the text get with the stlye attrivute is removed?

Comment: toggle a class.... so much cleaner.

Comment: @epascarello I am actually using multiple elements and each element has a specific color, and i want something that globally changes them instead of having to change them one by one, but i want a default thing to change them back to their unique color

Comment: Not sure why the unique color matters. They can still have unique colors with CSS. Maybe seeing details would help out.

Comment: not unique color in that way, I mean that I have a lot of text elements and a lot of them have different colors, and if a person doesn't like those colors, they can change that in settings and can set everything to red, orange, etc, or they can reset it back to default, that was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the color in a const and reset it to the element whenever you want :

```
const element = document.querySelector('#id');
```

// Get the computed styles

const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

// Get the color property

```
const color = styles.getPropertyValue('color');
element.style.color = "green";
```

// and later you can reset the color whenever you want:

```
element.style.color = color;
```